# Reuse custom Widget in Kivy app

Tags: python, frameworks, widget, kivy

I have a simple kivy app with the kv file associated as below, and I want to reuse my custom widget (included his appearance) in another kivy app. This is the widget to reuse:

```
class MyButton(Button):
pass

class MyComposit(Widget):
    button1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    lab = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        comp = MyComposit()
        return comp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv file:

```
<MyButton>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
           size: 30,30
           pos: self.pos

<MyComposit>
    size: 400,500
    button1: btn1
    lab: lb

    Label
        id: lb
        text: "label"
        pos: root.center_x,root.center_y

    MyButton:
       id: btn1
       text: "btn1"
       pos: root.x/3,200
```

Why do I get a blank page not showing my widget MyComposit in the app below?

```
from my_composit import MyComposit

class BigWidget(Widget):
    n = ObjectProperty(None)

class BigApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BigWidget()
        return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BigApp().run()
```

big.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9


<BigWidget>
    n: idcomp

    MyComposit:
        id: idcomp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new app includes no kv rule for the MyComposit widget, so it probably works fine but just doesn't show anything visible to you. Copy the relevant kv to big.kv to have it work.

You also probably want to look at layout classes, otherwise you will have to set the pos and size of everything by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know Layout classes but I haven't used them here to keep the code simple and short. Anyway, I know that copying relevant kv rules in big.kv obviously get MyComposit shown. But there isn't a way to inherit kv rules when I use a Widget already "defined" (whit his .kv file) ? Do I really have to copy all my kv code anytime?

Comment: @Carpo23 You can also load additional kivy files. See [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv) in the kivy documentation.

Comment: Widgets don't have kv files, and there is no implicit loading except the single kv file associated with the app class. You must load any extra files manually, or copy the rules contained therein to a file that is already loaded.